# firewall has blocked ssh. any wayarounds?

Tags: ssh, firewall

I want to connect to remote amazon `aws service`(EC2 instance) , and I would like to be able to `ssh` to it from my laptop while using the campus provided network (which has cyberoam firewall). However, they have pretty much every port blocked and `ssh` won't work. Is there anything i can do? does `ssh` run through port 80? I don't really know what to do .

All it says is :

> ssh_exchange_identification: read: Software caused connection abort

`ssh` works elsewhere.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set your SSH server to use port 80 (or 443 if 80 is used for a webserver). Just check the configuration file of your ssh server for more details!